# extend already defined java bean class

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, javabeans

What is the recommended way for extending an already defined bean class. 
Appreciate if you can answer with an example.
(in my case, I need to define a bean class, and later there will be more attributes that I might need to add, so I need a method of accommodating that in future)

Regards !!!

Comment: Why can't you start coding something and give up here?

Comment: What you are looking for is to create a new attribute with its getters and setters in the existing bean class whenever a method is called. But i believe you can not do that in the same existing bean class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of extending a bean class:

```
public class BeanExtension extends ExistingBean {
    private String myNewField;

    // getters and setters ommitted
}
```

Why is this question tagged web-services?

I assume the above example is not what you need. Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? If you have any example code you can share, do so.

Comment: Avoid juggling with reflection and maps. Take a look at Apache BeanUtils: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to declare it as "final". By default you can extend any class.

Comment: is there a possibility of using map data structure ?